# Firefox - how to rebind arrow keys?

Tags: firefox

I want to rebind the Down Arrow key to Tab key and Shift+Tab to Up Arrow key. I have installed the keyconfig addon - http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994.
I can rebind the keys with this addon but i can't find the source code for Down Arrow and Up Arrow key.

I assume that there is a javascript code that represent these two keyboard keys. Can someone tell me what is the code i should use for them?

Comment: Have you considered using autohotkey? This looks the simplest way for me but maybe you have good reasons not to.

Comment: I want to do the rebinding inside Firefox. I found the source code the two keys, but i don't know how to use them in a script:      DOM_VK_UP 0x26 (38) Up arrow;
DOM_VK_DOWN 0x28 (40) Down arrow

Comment: Well, AHK allows you to make bindings for a specific application, or window even...

Comment: I want to rebind the keys only when the bookmarks menu is opened and this can not be done with AHK script.

Comment: Indeed. But this is why I was asking :) You should add this precision in the question though.